# Applescript to Archive a set number of files

Tags: javascript, bash, shell, applescript

I'm teaching myself programming. I need help with a particular function. I'm looking to code this in applescript, so I can use this script in Automator. I'm open to a shell or javascript solution as well.

INPUT

I have a series of folders, where I've renamed all the files. Here's the relevant info:

1. There will always be a file called "main.png".
2. There will always be a file called "tab.png".
3. There is a varied set of images that are numbered incrementally from 01.png. Example:

01.png
02.png
03.png
...
30.png

4. I'd like to build a script that archives the files according to the following rules:

For the files in the archive:

1. It will always include the "main.png" file and the "tab.png" file.
2. For the remaining numbered files, the script will count them. I'm looking for the most amount of files that are available in these sets: 8,16,24, or 32.

Examples:

a. if 01.png...18.png exists, the script will select 01.png...16.png and put them into the archive.

b. if 01.png...15.png exits, the script will select 01.png...8.png and put them into an archive.

c. If 01.png....50.png exists, the script will select 01.png...32.png and put them into the archive.

3. Finally, the script will name the archive according to how many numbered files are chosen. So if there are only 8 numbered files, it will name the archive "8.zip". If there are 32 numbered files, it will name the archive "32.zip".

This is to help me figure out how many numbered files are in the zip, without opening it.

Thanks in advance! I really have no idea to do this, but couldn't find a good source on Stackoverflow.

Comment: _I really have no idea to do this_: then you should try first and teach yourself, is the best way to learn.

Comment: Marcs - Thanks. I've been struggling. I do now know archive files using automator. It's the particular filtration above that I'm struggling with.

Answer (score 0):

Warning : this site is not to ask someone else to develop your program, but instead to help you find solution for your script. As you say you need to learn yourselves, that's the best way...

However, we're closed to Christmas so, exceptionally, the program bellow does what you want. I added many comments to make sure you understand it and you can use it for learning :

```
set MyFolders to choose folder with prompt "select folders to be processed" with multiple selections allowed

repeat with aFolder in MyFolders
tell application "Finder"
    set myFiles to every file of aFolder
    set NbFiles to count of myFiles
    set MaxArchive to 8 * ((NbFiles - 2) div 8) -- round down number of files (-2 for main and tab) to multiple of 8 (=8,16,24,32,..)
    if MaxArchive = 0 then
        display alert "not enough file to create archive"
        return
    end if
    set ArchiveName to MaxArchive & ".zip" -- set name of archive to xx.zip : xx=number of files
    set ArchivePath to quoted form of ((POSIX path of aFolder) & ArchiveName) -- convert path to folder to unix path
    set FilestoArchive to {}
    set Nb to 0
    repeat with I from 1 to NbFiles -- loop through all files
        if (((name of item I of myFiles) contains "main.png") or ((name of item I of myFiles) contains "tab.png")) then -- add main or tab files anyway
            copy (item I of myFiles) to the end of FilestoArchive -- the file must be included in archive
        else
            if Nb < MaxArchive then
                copy (item I of myFiles) to the end of FilestoArchive -- the file must be included in archive
                set Nb to Nb + 1 --  incrementes file counter
            end if
        end if
    end repeat

    -- Now archive all files in the list FilestoArchive into ZIP file named ArchiveName in folder ArchivePath
    repeat with F in FilestoArchive
        set FPath to quoted form of POSIX path of (F as string)
        do shell script "zip -r " & ArchivePath & " " & FPath -- shell instruction to zip
    end repeat
end tell

end repeat -- loop to next folder to be processed
```

To know more about the zip command, go in Terminal and type 'man zip'. There are many options !

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm digging into this now. Definitely in this to learn. My problem is that I'm so new, I'm not even sure how to google an inquiry. I seriously appreciate this. Going to dig into it right now.

Comment: This is really elegant. It actually cuts out some of the other applescripts I had re: loading folders and dispensing them incrementally (which were add-on actions that I had to search out). Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I found a bug that I can't figure out how to fix. I think the issue is in the ArchivePath. Right now, the zip program is zipping all the folders that lead to the sub folder - instead of just the requested files. So it's zipping all hte folders in the hierarchy (including the Desktop folder) as empty, until it gets to the actual number count files. Is there a way to parse out all these higher level folders?

Comment: The 4th line of the script limits the list of items to 'every files' of the selected folder and then it should exclude any sub-folder. (fyi 'every item' would include both files and folders). So I don't see any reason why sub folders are included in zip file. you can check that by using command 'log' to see the list 'myFiles'. It does not include sub for me. About the ArchivePath, it just takes the path to the selected folder, in order to save the zip result in that folder too. if you want this zip to be save in the container of that folder, please use 'container' finder property.